# C++ operator & with enum evaluates to false

Tags: c++

Following code outputs reportAllDataRanges = 0.

```
BOOLEAN updateDataRanges = IsFirstUpdate || (m_uiDataRangeMode & IAdapterCommon::UpdatePinDataRanges);
BOOLEAN updateConstrainedDataRanges = m_uiDataRangeMode & IAdapterCommon::UpdatePinConstrainedDataRanges;
BOOLEAN reportAllDataRanges = m_uiDataRangeMode & IAdapterCommon::ReportAllDataRanges;

DPF_ENTER(("[CAdapterCommon::UpdatePinDescriptor(%p, %lu)] - m_uiDataRangeMode = %lu, updateDataRanges = %lu, updateConstrainedDataRanges = %lu, reportAllDataRanges = %lu, a & b = %lu, b = %lu", PinDescriptor, IsFirstUpdate, m_uiDataRangeMode, updateDataRanges, updateConstrainedDataRanges, reportAllDataRanges, m_uiDataRangeMode & IAdapterCommon::ReportAllDataRanges, IAdapterCommon::ReportAllDataRanges));
```

---

```
[CAdapterCommon::UpdatePinDescriptor(FFFFF8064CCE42F0, 1)] - m_uiDataRangeMode = 3070, updateDataRanges = 1, updateConstrainedDataRanges = 64, reportAllDataRanges = 0, a & b = 512, b = 512
```

---

```
typedef enum : UINT32
{
    None = 0,
    UseDataRanges = 1 << 0,
    UseDiscreteDataRanges = 1 << 1,
    RaiseUpdateEvent = 1 << 2,
    RaiseUpdatePinDescriptor = 1 << 3,
    DoNotUpdateOriginalDescriptor = 1 << 4,
    UpdatePinDataRanges = 1 << 5,
    UpdatePinConstrainedDataRanges = 1 << 6,
    UseDataRangeIntersection = 1 << 7,
    UseProposedDataFormat = 1 << 8,
    ReportAllDataRanges = 1 << 9,
    DataRangeIntersectionAcceptAllRanges = 1 << 10,
    SupportedDataRangesFirst = 1 << 11,
} DataRangeModeEnum;
```

---

shouldnt

```
BOOLEAN value = 3070 & 512;
```

evaluate to TRUE? (larger than zero)?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. As @M.M. points out, we don't know what `BOOLEAN` is.

Comment: BOOLEAN is UCHAR. I believe that this explain everything! Thank you guys!!! (I am doing Windows Kernel driver development) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what is happening is that `BOOLEAN` is a typedef for a 1-byte type. E.g. in Microsoft's Windows headers, it is a typedef for `unsigned char` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)).

The value of `3070 & 512` is `512`. Assigning `512` to `unsigned char` gives the result of `0`.

To avoid this problem you can do one of the following things:

- Use `bool` instead of `BOOLEAN`.
- Use `!!(x & y)` instead of `x & y`.
- Use `(x & y) == y`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using BOOLEAN type from the `<Windows.h>` header which is a typedef for the BYTE type which is a typedef for unsinged char type which can hold values from 0 - 255 and not the 512 to which the `3070 & 512` expression evaluates. There is an overflow that results in the value of 0 which is equivalent to `FALSE`.